# Using text file in assets folder to match and redirect to next activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the code of my function which is used:

```
 public void redirecttohome() {
            //variable init
            edtpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtpass);
            edtuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
            String text="";   
    try {
       InputStream is = getAssets().open("login.txt");
       int size = is.available();
       byte [] buffer = new byte[size];
       is.read(buffer);
       text = new String (buffer);          
       if (edtuserid.getText().toString().equals(text) && edtpass.getText().toString().equals(text)) {
          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
      }
     else {Snackbar.make(parent_view, "Invalid UserID and Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
          is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e("Error!", "Error occured while reading text file from Internal Storage!");
    }
 }
```

I want to check user id and password from my text which is saved is assets directory and redirect to home activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking String grabbed from file "login.txt" for equality to both userId and password enterd to your editTexts. For example, login.txt has something like "user1, password" and you have entered "user1" to you edittext for userId and "password" to your edittext for password. Checking for equality of content of each edittext and info in file will fail. "user1, password" != "user1" && "user1, password" != "password". You need to check userId with only part before comma sign of your text from "login.txt". The same with password: check password (after comma sign and space).

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand Please can you help to understand.

Comment: You need to split somehow information stored in file so it will be 2 separate strings. one for userId and other for Password. And check each of them accordingly with the needed EditText's text. E.g. If you will have credentials stored in file in format "userId|password". Then use this code next to your line: text = new String (buffer);          
       String[] creds = text.split(":");
        if (edtuserid.getText().toString().equals(creds[0]) && edtpass.getText().toString().equals(creds[1])) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }

Comment: Thank you for your reply i will try this .

Comment: Thank You so much @Oleksandr Martynets. I have tried this and it work thank you once again.

Comment: @MadhusudanPandey Then mark this answer as correct one? ;-)